# keyerror in drf serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer like this :

```py
class LocationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    
    lat = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6),
    lng = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6),
    term = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
```

in views.py :

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def get_prefer_locations(request):        
    serilizer = LocationSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serilizer.is_valid():
        print(request.data)
        location_obj=Location(serilizer.data['lat'],serilizer.data['lng'],serilizer.data['term'])
        address = location_obj.convert_latandlong_to_address()
```

and this is the Location class that i have defined :

```py
class Location:
    def __init__(self, latitude,longitude,term):
        self.lat = latitude,
        self.lng=longitude,
        self.term=term
        
    def convert_latandlong_to_address(self):

        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")
        location = geolocator.reverse(self.lat+","+self.lng)
        address = location.raw['address']
        return address
```

when i printed request.data in terminal i got this :

```
{'lat': '29.623411959216355', 'lng': '52.49860312690429', 'term': 'cafe'}
```

but i got this error :

```
  File "/home/admin1/mizbanproject/location/preferlocation/api/views.py", line 15, in get_prefer_locations
    location_obj = Location(serilizer.data['lat'],serilizer.data['lng'],serilizer.data['term'])
KeyError: 'lat'
```

and this is the json i am sending via postman:

```
{
    "lat":"29.623411959216355",
    "lng":"52.49860312690429",
    "term":"cafe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're validating your serializer, the validated data should be accessible in `validated_data`:

```
location_obj=Location(serilizer.validated_data['lat'],serilizer.validated_data['lng'],serilizer.validated_data['term'])
```

Comment: I have already tried it,not working.

Comment: Take a look inside serializer instead of printing `request.data`

Comment: Thank you i printed the serilizer.data and found out it did not have lat and lng within it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the serilizers to below and it works the problem was in max_digits and decimal_places :

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    lat = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=25,decimal_places=15)
    lng = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=15)
    term = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
```